# Table with figures

Tags: pdftex, multirow

I have a special table layout in which i want to place figures. The table looks like this:

```
"-------------------------------------------------"
" Figure 1       | Figure 2                      |"
"----------------|                               |"
" Figure 3       |                               |"   
"-------------------------------------------------"
```

I created this table with the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{tabular}{l l}

\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Figure1} & \multirow{2}
{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{Figure2}} \\

\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]
{Figure3} 

\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

However when it comes to layouting the table it places the figure somewhere in the vertical center of the multirow cell, like this:

```
"-------------------------------------------------"
" Figure 1       |                               |"
"----------------| Figure 2                      |"
" Figure 3       |                               |"   
"-------------------------------------------------"
```

How do I get it up to the desired position (same top position as Figure 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/table/multirow.pdf documents another optional parameter for fiddling with the text positioning:

```
\multirow{nrows}[bigstruts]{width}[fixup]{text}
```

Simply try a few lengths in `fixup`; `12pt` or `1em` may be good starting points, but it will take some trial and error whenever the table formatting changes to find a new, good position.

(I wonder what would happen if you added a `\vfill` at the end of `text` -- will it fill the table cell or will it fill far too much?)

Comment: NICE. The Fixup worked! You have to play with the parameter but thats okay for me!! \vfill did not work. But I'm not a profesional and I cannot say why specifically